# Twig lookup table

Tags: php, twig

Am I stuck with a bunch of IF statements or extending Twig with a custom function, or is there a better way to implement a lookup table using Twig?  For instance, maybe something like the following (but using Twig language), or even something better?

```
public function getLookUpTable1($type_id)
{
    $db=[0=>'AI',1=>'A0',2=>'AV',3=>'BI',4=>'BO',5=>'BV'];
    return $db[$type_id];
}

public function getLookUpTable2($type_id)
{
    switch($type_id) {
        case 0:$v='AI';break;
        case 1:$v='AO';break;
        case 2:$v='AV';break;
        case 3:$v='BI';break;
        case 4:$v='BO';break;
        case 5:$v='BV';break;
    }
    return $v;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the twig [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) funtionality

Comment: are you using twig in combination with some framework like symfony?

Comment: @Matteo  No framework.  Yes, I know about macros, but one still needs to implement the logic.  I am starting to think extending a filter would be the best choice.

Comment: a non conventional way is that you can use the trans filter to translate simple strings or variables. In your example you can concat with a prefix for the key and set the value in a translated value. Let me know if you want some sample or if the idea can be good